# Rails Has Many Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, active-record-query

User has many comments and comments belong to user. Comment table has status column which is boolean type.

Now I want to get users whose last comment has status true.

How can this be done in ActiveRecord query?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query (get users those last comment has status true)

```
User.joins(:comments)
    .where('comments.created_at = (SELECT MAX(comments.created_at) FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id = users.id)')
    .where('comments.status = true')
    .group('users.id')
```

This actually requires a sub query, so the idea is first fetching out all users last comment and filtering out with status as true to find out the users id with help of join.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user_ids = Comment.where(status: true).pluck(:user_id)
```

Then

```
User.where(id: @user_ids)
```

Otherwise use a join, will give you all the fields from User and Comment for every result.

```
Comment.joins(:user).where(user_id: @user_ids)
```

Comment: Not the right answer because I did not mention Question model any where. also I want to get the users those last comment has status false.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = []
User.all.each do |user|
  users << user if user.comments && user.comments.last.status
end

users # list of all user whose last comment status = true
```

`users` object consist all the users whose last comment status is true.

Comment: I want a rails active record query no loop.

Comment: @AnandShrivastava based on rails guide this is the correct answer (if it works). This is a Query for retrieving multiple objects in Batches
Also, please explain us why you need an active record query and no loop
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

Comment: Because it is obvious that loop will take more time in compare to active record query and I consider it to be not good practice suppose if so many users like 10000 etc then load time will be more. does it make sense?